# Collision works after going to the other side

Tags: java, collision

I'm making a simple pong game, and I need to make it so that the player paddle cannot go out of the screen.

It works, however if I go to the edge, go up and go to the same edge again, it works the first time but not the second. If I go to the top edge, and then the bottom it works fine. I cannot figure this out, so I would appreciate any help ;)

Game.java:

http://pastebin.com/NfapK339

Screen.java

http://pastebin.com/Z0BB34Sn

Ball.java

http://pastebin.com/yDVMTg6e

Player.java

http://pastebin.com/rBu0hSd8

Computer.java

http://pastebin.com/dRa1SWZe

Comment: please reduce the amount of code and then include it in your question. Don't put pastebin Links here.

Answer (score 0):

What code stops the player paddle from going outside of the screen. instead of just posting all your code show the stub that does what you're asking as well.

Just had another look and saw the check was being done in the keypress.

Try putting the check in the player.update() method. Update it to parse in a height

```
public void update(int height) {
    if(y < 0)
    { y = 0; }
    else if( y > height )
    { y = height }
    else
    { y = y + yVelocity; }
}
```